# Why Non-Threaded is working faster than Multi-Threaded?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was comparing threaded and non-threaded application, How and why the non-threaded one is faster?

```
// makes thread
private void MakeThreads(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(PerformOperation);
        _threads.Add(thread);
        thread.Start();
    }
}

// any operation
private void PerformOperation()
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
    {
        j++;
    }
}

private void Threaded_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int outer = 1000;
    const int inner = 2;

    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < outer; i++)
    {
        MakeThreads(inner);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;

    MessageBox.Show("Time Taken by " + (outer * inner) + " Operations: " +
        String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10),
        "Result",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

private void NonThreaded_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int outer = 1000;
    const int inner = 2;

    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < inner * outer; i++)
    {
        PerformOperation();
    }
    timer.Stop();
    TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;

    MessageBox.Show("Time Taken by " + (outer * inner) + " Operations: " +
        String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10),
        "Result",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Threaded Time : 00:19:43
Non-Threaded Time : 00:08:72

Why my threading is taking too much time? Am I making some mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are creating too many threads. Creating threads takes more time also your code is wrong, you are not waiting for threads to finish.

```
private void Threaded_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int outer = 1000;
    const int inner = 2;

    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.For(0, inner*outer, i=> {

        PerformOperation();
    });
    timer.Stop();
    TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;

    MessageBox.Show("Time Taken by " + (outer * inner) + " Operations: " +
        String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10),
        "Result",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: If I wait for a thread to get finished then what is the advantage of multithreading?

Comment: You don't wait for single thread, you are waiting for all of them to finish. first try this and then tell me if you don't notice the advantage.

Comment: Now that is something that I really wanted. Thanks, this worked.

Comment: Also, a loop to  999999 is a couple 9's short of a reasonable amount of work to thread off.

Answer (score 2):

Method "**Threaded_Click()**" will execute code on thread which is background thread(non UI thread). While method "**NonThreaded_Click()**" will execute code on UI thread(foreground thread).
That is the reason it executes earlier than other one.

You can make both of them to execute on same time interval by making change "**MakeThreads()**" as below

```
private void MakeThreads(int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {                
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(PerformOperation);             
                task.Wait();
            }
        }
```

But this will freeze UI thread.

Comment: This is also helpful thanks. It has minimized time. But Akash Kava's answer is the best